# How do I inject javascript code via webview?

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Basically what I want to do is this [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60426/manipulate-html-document-loaded-into-webbrowser-control) but I can't seem to find something similar for webview XAML control. What I ultimately need to do, is capture an incoming json file from the webview. As is, I get a bad request from the server and unsupported file exception from the webview. I thought about injecting a javascript so that it would alert me, I could get the body of the incoming json  and bypass all the errors.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main things you can do:

1. Call functions programically
2. Inject any code by using the HTML string

#### Function Calling

You can use `InvokeScript` to call javascript functions.

If you have in a webpage with a script:

```
<script lang="en-us" type="text/javascript">
   function myFunction() {
       alert("I am an alert box!");
   }
</script>
```

Then you can in C# call:

```
MyWebview.InvokeScript("myFunction", null);
```

Which will execute the script function `myFunction`.

#### Injecting Text

If you download the HTML page and all other needed files(using the Windows HttpClient), you can inject any code by manipulating and then Navigating to string.

Lets say you want to change the above script to add another function, "HelloWorld", then you can

1. Search the file for something you know will be there, such as: `<script lang=\"en-us\" type=\"text/javascript\">`
2. Using string manipulation, add the desired text, such as a function (but this can be anything)
3. Navigate to the String

The C# code:

```
string MyWebPageString = GetWebpageString(WebpageUri);
string ScriptTagString = "<script lang=\"en-us\" type=\"text/javascript\">";
int IndexOfScriptTag = MyWebPageString.IndexOf(ScriptTagString);
int LengthOfScriptTag = ScriptTagString.Length;
string InsertionScriptString = "function SayHelloWorld() { window.external.notify(\"Hello World!\");} ";
MyWebPageString = MyWebPageString.Insert(IndexOfScriptTag + LengthOfScriptTag + 1, InsertionScriptString);
MyWebview.NavigateToString(MyWebPageString);
```

The result will be that the navigated to Webpage will look like this:

```
<script lang="en-us" type="text/javascript"> function SayHelloWorld() { window.external.notify("Hello World!");}
   function myFunction() {
       alert("I am an alert box!");
   }
</script>
```

Since the injection can be applied to any area, even the HTML, you should be able to figure something out.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

This answer was based on [this MSDN blog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx)